# Enable submit button whithout keypress event (autofilled hidden input)

Tags: jquery

I have a Form which has 2 hidden fields that are auto-filled with an ajax response with jquery autocomplete plugin.

This two fields are the only one i requiere to submit the form and i don't know how to check if are filled to enable the submit button.

Thanks!

Comment: https://api.jquery.com/submit/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without your HTML, I'm just going to make up some elements inside this code.

## jQuery

```
var filled = $('form input').filter(function(){
        return $(this).val() !== '';
    }).length === 2;
```

Now the `filled` variable will be a boolean, checking that exactly 2 values are filled from the selector `form input`. You can change the code inside the function to verify the input more specifically than just not blank.